# Difficulty(3) in understanding Thm 4.1 in Stein & Shakarachi Fourier Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I do not understand why the writer said:"If $f$ is continuous everywhere, then it is uniformly continuous" in this paragraph:[image]

Could anyone explain this for me please?

The detailed theorem and its prove is found here: [Difficulty(2) in understanding Thm 4.1 in Stein & Shakarachi Fourier Analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2258671/difficulty2-in-understanding-thm-4-1-in-stein-shakarachi-fourier-analysis)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not providing context (or rather, you want us to chase it down through two other questions). The domain of $f$ is the circle, which is compact. A continuous function on a compact set is uniformly continuous.

Comment: I am sorry if this annoys people, I will not do it another time, thank u for your answer.

Comment: No worries. But, usually, the expectation here is that you type a self-contained question.